# How to count the number of a specific digit in each cell in R

Tags: r

I've got a numeric vector in my dataframe and I'm trying to create a new variable that is a count of the number of 5's in the digits of each cell. For example 2451 would return 1, 57590 would return 2.

I'm able to just count the number of digits with
    `as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(a), "")[[1]])`

but I haven't been able to add in the sum == 5 across all the cells in my dataframe. Any thoughts would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
library(stringr)
x <- c(2425, 55234535, 2436.755)
str_count(x, '5')
#[1] 1 4 2
```

Comment: that downvoting is crazy

Comment: The upvoting is crazy no less though (not the downvoter)

Comment: ...but understandable...

Comment: Why is that? This is an obvious dupe I'd guess. Four upvotes for the first minute is not understandable usually. Here's an obvious dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427385/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-occurrence-of-a-given-character-in-each-row-of-a

Comment: I don't get it. So If I answer a dupe my time and effort does not count?

Comment: I usually mark dupes, but If it's an easy one then it takes less time to answer it

Comment: No one said it's not -  but answering an obvious dupe doesn't deserve 4 upvotes in the first minute one would think. And if you think it's an obvious dupe and you are answering it instead of closing- you are doing more harm than value.

Comment: Ok, on that manner I agree with you. I was also a bit surprised by 4 votes within the 1st minute ... :p .

Comment: However, what is more crazy are the 2 upvotes on the question...

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this answer and I agree they shouldn't do so.

Comment: Anyway, I do that for learning R myself (have only been using it for 5 months now, and I have no prior knowledge of coding), not for points. Well, I guess points keep things interesting :)