# Search for a specific number of characters in a string

Tags: r, regex

Wanted to know the most efficient way of searching for a string with a specific number of a characters. E.g. how can I select #2, #4, #5 from the below strings using only the number of forward slashes ?

```
1. d/e/b/f
2. d/e
3. e/c/b/f/d
4. e/d
5. x/y
```

Comment: See [How to calculate the number of occurrence of a given character in each row of a column of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427385)

Comment: This looks quite complicated! Is there a regex syntax to address this?

Comment: Why regex at all? Just count the `/` occurrences using `stringr::str_count`. Or, there are other options listed in that thread.

Comment: Okay! this rule will be part of other scanning rules so I was hoping there was a way to do this in one regex statement. Anyways, thanks for your input!

Comment: Then you need to describe the real problem. Right now, it is an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple step using `str_count`

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.table(col1 = c('d/e/b/f', 'd/e', 'e/c/b/f/d', 'e/d', 'x/y'))

df[, slash_count := sapply(col1, str_count, pattern = '\\/', USE.NAMES = F)]
print(df[slash_count == 1, 'col1'])

   col1
1:  d/e
2:  e/d
3:  x/y
```

Comment: Think the str_count from stringr will work okay, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward:

```
subset(df,nchar(gsub("[^/]","",df$col1))==1)
  col1
2  d/e
4  e/d
5  x/y
```

or you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df%>%filter(str_count(col1,"/")==1)
  col1
1  d/e
2  e/d
3  x/y
```