# Iterating through multiple substrings in a .txt file in base R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I've been tasked with calculating the GC content of a FASTA file using base R (no packages). My problem is that I don't know how to pragmatically iterate through the sequence while storing the sequence name and also the number of Cs and Gs.

Example FASTA file I can read in (as a .txt file):

```
>T7_promoter
ATTAGACGAG
>T3_promoter
TTTGCGCGAAATTTTTTTTT
```

*There are no quotes here but the > designates a distinct sequence.

Such that my output will be something conceptually similar to -

```
T7_promoter: 0.4 (ratio of GC from # of Gs and Cs)
T3_promoter: 0.25
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. I am currently using `readLines()` to pass the file through. I tried using `unlist(strsplit())` per element that `strsplit()` naturally produces to try and store each sequence as an element in a list. Then I could iterate through each element to get calculations but my executions have not been successful.

Comment: Running `output <- dput(x, file = "rosalind_gc_FASTA.txt")` gives me `[1] 5`. I'm unfamiliar with this function, what is it used for?

Comment: Related post on "how to count a character within a string": https://stackoverflow.com/q/12427385/680068

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dat <- read.csv("file.txt", sep = " ", header = FALSE)` to read the lines to a dataframe.

Then you can count the number of Gs and Cs with

```
dat$Gs <- lengths(regmatches(lines$V2, gregexpr("G", dat$V2)))
dat$Cs <- lengths(regmatches(lines$V2, gregexpr("C", dat$V2)))
```

The last needed thing would be the calculation of the ratio:
`dat$ratio <- dat$Gs/dat$Cs`