# Efficiently ranking string matches by number of matched terms

Tags: r, regex, stringr, grepl

**Summary:** how to most efficiently count multiple regex matches and rank results by incidence? Are there semantic approaches that should be used instead of regex?

Sample data for illustration:

```
sample_string <- c("Total - Main mode of commuting for the employed labour force aged 15 years and over in private households with a usual place of work or no fixed workplace address - 25% sample data", 
"Total - Language used most often at work for the population in private households aged 15 years and over who worked since January 1, 2015 - 25% sample data", 
"Number of market income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households - 25% sample data", 
"Number of employment income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households", 
"Total - Major field of study - Classification of Instructional Programs (CIP) 2016 for the population aged 15 years and over in private households - 25% sample data", 
"Total - Selected places of birth for the recent immigrant population in private households - 25% sample data", 
"Total - Commuting duration for the employed labour force aged 15 years and over in private households with a usual place of work or no fixed workplace address - 25% sample data", 
"Number of market income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households", 
"Employment income (%)", "Total - Aboriginal ancestry for the population in private households - 25% sample data", 
"Without employment income", "With after-tax income", "1 household maintainer", 
"Spending 30% or more of income on shelter costs", "Total - Highest certificate, diploma or degree for the population aged 25 to 64 years in private households - 25% sample data"
)
```

And a sample string query containing multiple terms

```
sample_query <- c("after tax income")
```

It is easy to check for a match of the string query using `grepl`.

```
sample_string[grepl(sample_query, sample_string)]
```

But obviously this wouldn't work here because there is no exact match, because the actual term is `after-tax income`. An alternative is to separate the search query into parts and check against that.

```
sample_string[grepl(paste(unlist(strsplit(sample_query, " +")), collapse = "|"), sample_string)]
```

This would work, but would return too many results, because it matches against any instance of any of those terms.

```
[1] "Number of market income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households - 25% sample data"
[2] "Number of employment income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households"              
[3] "Number of market income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households"                  
[4] "Employment income (%)"                                                                            
[5] "Without employment income"                                                                        
[6] "With after-tax income"                                                                            
[7] "Spending 30% or more of income on shelter costs"
```

**The question: how to effectively return the closest match based on number of individual matches?**

Applying some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427385/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-occurrence-of-a-given-character-in-each-row-of-a), and adding ordering and matching leads to monstrosity:

```
sample_string[grepl(paste(unlist(strsplit(sample_query, " +")),
                          collapse = "|"),
                    sample_string)][order(-lengths(regmatches(
                      sample_string[grepl(paste(unlist(strsplit(sample_query, " +")),
                                                collapse = "|"),
                                          sample_string)],
                      gregexpr(paste(unlist(
                        strsplit(sample_query, " +")
                      ),
                      collapse = "|"),
                      sample_string[grepl(paste(unlist(strsplit(sample_query, " +")),
                                                collapse = "|"),
                                          sample_string)])
                    )))]
```

Which returns what I want - a list of all strings with at least one match, ordered by the number of matches.

```
[1] "With after-tax income"                                                                            
[2] "Number of market income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households - 25% sample data"
[3] "Number of employment income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households"              
[4] "Number of market income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households"                  
[5] "Employment income (%)"                                                                            
[6] "Without employment income"                                                                        
[7] "Spending 30% or more of income on shelter costs"
```

Cleaning the above monstrosity up a little bit:

```
to_match <- paste(unlist(strsplit(sample_query, " +")),collapse = "|")
results <- sample_string[grepl(to_match,sample_string)]
results[order(-lengths(regmatches(results,gregexpr(to_match,results))))]
```

I can live with this, but is there a way to make this more concise? And, **what I'm wondering is whether this is even the best way to approach this?**

I am aware of `stringr::str_count` and `stringi::stri_count_regex`. This for a package and I'm trying to avoid adding additional dependencies , but if these are much more efficient I am fine to use that instead.

Or, alternatively, is a string distance alternative a better option? Is it still better when checking against thousands of long strings?

The intent is to help users find relevant information, perhaps there is something a little bit more semantically oriented that would make sense.

Comment: Since your code is already working, you could try to migrate your question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @dshkol Please see my response, it is done in base R, it uses levenshtein (edit) distance and retrieves the single most relevant sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can be improved but here is one way of doing what you are after using Levenshtein Distance:

```
# Desired query scalar: actual_query => character vector
actual_query <- "after tax income"

# Separate words in query: query_words => character vector: 
query_words <- unlist(strsplit(tolower(actual_query), "[^a-z]+"))

# Calculate n (scalar) for n-grams: word_count => integer vector
word_count <- length(query_words)

# Split each word preserving any non-character values: 
# sentence_word_split => character vector
sentence_word_split <- strsplit(tolower(sample_string), "\\s+")

# Split original sentences into n-grams (relative to query length): 
# n_grams => list 
n_grams <- lapply(sentence_word_split, function(x){
              sapply(seq_along(x), function(i){
                paste(x[i:min(length(x), ((i+word_count)-1))], sep = " ", collapse = " ")
      }
    )
  }
)

# Rank ngrams based on the frequency of their occurence in sample string: 
# ordered_n_gram => character vector
ordered_ngram_count <- trimws(names(sort(table(unlist(n_grams)), decreasing = TRUE)), "both")

# Combine the query with each of its elements: revised_query => character vector 
revised_query <- c(actual_query, unlist(strsplit(actual_query, "\\s+")))

# Use levenshtein distance to determine similarity of revised_query 
# to the expressions in the ordered_ngram_count: lev_dist_df => data.frame
lev_dist_df <- setNames(data.frame(sapply(seq_along(revised_query), 
                    function(i){
                       adist(revised_query[i], ordered_ngram_count)
                      }
                    )), gsub("\\s+", "_", revised_query))

# Example of applying function returning string element in sample string 
# with the minimum edit distance: sample_string element => stdout (console)
grep(grep(ordered_ngram_count[sapply(seq_along(ncol(lev_dist_df)),
                                     function(i) {
                                       which.min(lev_dist_df[, i])
                                     })], sample_string,
          value = TRUE),
     sample_string,
     value = TRUE)
```

Cleaner version of above:

```
# Desired query scalar: sample_query => character vector
sample_query <- "after tax income"

# Separate words in query: query_words => character vector: 
query_words <- unlist(strsplit(tolower(sample_query), "[^a-z]+"))

# Calculate n (scalar) for n-grams: word_count => integer vector
word_count <- length(query_words)

# Split each word preserving any non-character values: 
# sentence_word_split => character vector
sentence_word_split <- strsplit(tolower(sample_string), "\\s+")

# Split original sentences into n-grams (relative to query length): 
# n_grams => list 
n_grams <- lapply(sentence_word_split, function(x){
    sapply(seq_along(x), function(i){
      paste(x[i:min(length(x), ((i+word_count)-1))], sep = " ", collapse = " ")
      }
    )
  }
)

# Rank ngrams based on the frequency of their occurence in sample string: 
# ordered_n_gram => character vector
ordered_ngram_count <- trimws(names(sort(table(unlist(n_grams)), decreasing = TRUE)), "both")

# Use levenshtein distance to determine similarity of revised_query 
# to the expressions in the ordered_ngram_count: lev_dist_df => data.frame
lev_dist_df <- setNames(data.frame(sapply(seq_along(sample_query), 
                                          function(i){
                                            adist(sample_query[i], ordered_ngram_count)
                                          })), gsub("\\s+", "_", sample_query))

# Example of applying function returning string element in sample string 
# with the minimum edit distance: sample_string element => stdout (console)
grep(grep(ordered_ngram_count[which.min(lev_dist_df[,1])], sample_string,
          value = TRUE), sample_string, value = TRUE)
```

Data:

```
sample_string <- c("Total - Main mode of commuting for the employed labour force aged 15 years and over in private households with a usual place of work or no fixed workplace address - 25% sample data", 
                   "Total - Language used most often at work for the population in private households aged 15 years and over who worked since January 1, 2015 - 25% sample data", 
                   "Number of market income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households - 25% sample data", 
                   "Number of employment income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households", 
                   "Total - Major field of study - Classification of Instructional Programs (CIP) 2016 for the population aged 15 years and over in private households - 25% sample data", 
                   "Total - Selected places of birth for the recent immigrant population in private households - 25% sample data", 
                   "Total - Commuting duration for the employed labour force aged 15 years and over in private households with a usual place of work or no fixed workplace address - 25% sample data", 
                   "Number of market income recipients aged 15 years and over in private households", 
                   "Employment income (%)", "Total - Aboriginal ancestry for the population in private households - 25% sample data", 
                   "Without employment income", "With after-tax income", "1 household maintainer", 
                   "Spending 30% or more of income on shelter costs", "Total - Highest certificate, diploma or degree for the population aged 25 to 64 years in private households - 25% sample data"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach. There's an error at the end `Error in ncol(lev_dist_mat) : object 'lev_dist_mat' not found`, but I think that can be solved by replacing `lev_dist_mat` with the `lev_dist_df` object you created. I will upvote but leave accepting a little bit longer to see if there are any other answers using different approaches. Thanks!

Comment: @dshkol good pick-up you are correct that was mean to be lev_dist_df. No worries, best of luck with your problem. And please accept the solution if no other solutions come through meeting your spec !