# How to count number of times a letter appears in a column based on row in r

Tags: r, sequence

I'm trying to count the number of times a letter appears in my columns based on the row. For example my table looks a little bit like this

| Sample | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| F1 | VALILQNVDLPN |
| F2 | GLAEDIENEVVQITWnR |

I am trying to figure out the total amount of times the letter "N" appears, whether its capital or lowercase, and also how many times a lower case letter appears in each sample. Could anyone please point me towards a solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you tell us, what you tried so far?

Comment: Please see the following answer, which might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427545/5493449